# mysql max function only returns 1 row

Tags: mysql

I have the following query to my db:

```
$examCnt = query("select * from apExams");
```

when I print that out I get:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2023-08-24
        [exam] => 1
        [question] => 1
        [active] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2023-08-24
        [exam] => 1
        [question] => 2
        [active] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2023-08-25
        [exam] => 3
        [question] => 1
        [active] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2023-08-25
        [exam] => 3
        [question] => 2
        [active] => 0
    )

)
```

but when I run the following query:

```
 $examCnt = query("select *, max(exam) as cnt from apExams");
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-08-24
            [exam] => 1
            [question] => 1
            [active] => 0
            [cnt] => 3
        )

)
```

Why don't I get back all 4 records with cnt = 3?

Comment: no, I asked for select * , max(exam)...  isn't the select * asking for everything?

Comment: From the manual `"If you use an aggregate function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows"`

Comment: It's a `MAX()` function.  It's supposed to return the max.  If it's returning more than 1 row, it won't do its job.

Comment: `*` asks for every column, not every row. It's just a shortcut for listing all the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't use `GROUP BY`, any use of an aggregate function causes the entire table to be aggregated into one row in the result set.

To get what you want, you should use `MAX(cnt)` in a subquery.

```
SELECT *, (SELECT MAX(exam) FROM apExams) AS cnt 
FROM apExams
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM apExams
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(exam) AS cnt
    FROM apExams
) AS x
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with Group By as follows.

```
$examCnt = query("select *, max(exam) as cnt from apExams GROUP BY id");
```

The reason it returned only one row is that (*,max()) returns the maximum value in a set of values appending max(); thus, you need to use GROUP BY to retrieve each row.

I just realised that group by cannot meet the need, definitely using subquery.

The query result without group by:

[image]

The query result with group by:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good answer, but would be nice to see the results as a inline markdown table instead of linked images.